# Treat a formula like any other text value when exporting to Excel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I've built a reporting solution where the data can be exported as Excel. Using PHPExcel, this work's beautifully. But, we had a need to build dashboard style template sheets and have them inserted into the output at runtime, including formulas. I have all of that working fine, my issue is that sometimes these dashboard templates are fairly complex and PHPExcel chokes on the formula's when it tries to output.

I've spent a considerable amount of time finding workarounds and even went as far as [forking my own branch](https://github.com/cillosis/PHPExcel/commit/400f4b8f56f9270705294fa12d13656f331635d2) and adding a method of disabling calculation that would try to stop the formulas from being processed, but could not get it to work. I've also tried disabling calculation cache.

@MarkBaker has done a fantastic job with this library, and I have seen multiple times where he has mentioned this is not designed for modifying files, but if done very carefully, it seems to work.

My issue is, how can I tell PHPExcel to **stop** trying to calculate formulas? I want it to treat them just like any other text value and let Excel itself handle validation. Is this possible?

As an example, here is a formula that PHPExcel appears to not like:

```
=IFERROR(IF($L$3="UNITS",COUNTIF('K1_Current_Accounts'!$M$2:$M$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!H5)+COUNTIF('K1_Current_Available'!$M$2:$M$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!H5),IF($L$3="Cost Basis",SUMIF('K1_Current_Accounts'!$M$2:$M$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!H5,'K1_Current_Accounts'!$E$2:$E$10000)+SUMIF('K1_Current_Available'!$M$2:$M$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!H5,'K1_Current_Available'!$E$2:$E$10000),IF($L$3="Notes",SUMIFS('K1_Current_Accounts'!$AA$2:$AA$10000,'K1_Current_Accounts'!$M$2:$M$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!H5,'K1_Current_Accounts'!$R$2:$R$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!$A$7)+SUMIFS('K1_Current_Accounts'!$AA$2:$AA$10000,'K1_Current_Accounts'!$M$2:$M$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!H5,'K1_Current_Accounts'!$R$2:$R$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!$A$8)+SUMIFS('K1_Current_Accounts'!$AA$2:$AA$10000,'K1_Current_Accounts'!$M$2:$M$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!H5,'K1_Current_Accounts'!$R$2:$R$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!$A$9),IF($L$3="Cash",SUMIFS('K1_Historical_Accounts'!$AC$2:$AC$10000,'K1_Historical_Accounts'!$M$2:$M$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!H5,'K1_Historical_Accounts'!$R$2:$R$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!$A$10))))),"")
```

[image]

I read that `SUMIFS` can cause problems, but I have no clue how to refactor those to `SUMPRODUCT` as suggested (these dashboards are built by business development teams). Also, we have our ranges for columns go to like 10000 because ranges like A:A do not work either. They work fine in Excel, so if I could just get PHPExcel to stop trying to validate everything and just let it through, my life will be glorious!

### **EDIT**

Looking further at the stack trace, it seems to start happening when it tries to write a chart:

[image]

### **EDIT 2**

Looking at the chart generation as the source of this problem, there is only one chart and it's data source is `='Sales History'!$Y$4:$CR$5`, which I can see it for sure tries to process, but that shouldn't cause an issue as it is a relatively simple reference.

Comment: Note, currently working on an implementation of the SUMIFS() function for PHPExcel

Comment: Awesome thanks Mark!

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent PHPExcel from calculating formulas when writing by setting the Writer's `preCalculateFormulas` flag to false using

```
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
```

**EDIT**

I've made some experimental changes to the Excel2007 Writer to disable cell calculations for charts:

In `/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Chart.php` I've added a new property

```
protected $calculateCellValues;
```

And modified the `writeChart()` method to accept an additional argument:

```
public function writeChart(PHPExcel_Chart $pChart = null, $calculateCellValues = true)
{
    $this->calculateCellValues = $calculateCellValues;
```

and modified the subsequent call to `$pChart->refresh()`

```
//    Ensure that data series values are up-to-date before we save
if ($this->calculateCellValues) {
    $pChart->refresh();
}
```

And in the `save()` method of `/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php` I've modified the call to `writeChart()` around line 300 to read:

```
$objZip->addFromString(
    'xl/charts/chart' . ($chartCount + 1) . '.xml', 
    $this->getWriterPart('Chart')
        ->writeChart($chart, $this->preCalculateFormulas)
);
```

(ie. I've injected `$this->preCalculateFormulas` into the chart writer.)

A provisional test shows that MS Excel will trigger a recalculation itself when the resultant xlsx files are opened.... but this hasn't been a full test

Comment: I've tried that. It defaults to `false` also in `PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007` line 39. In that specific writer (the one I need), it passes that value in on line 290 for worksheets, yet still tries to validate the formula's anyway. I'm trying to do everything I can to avoid writing my own library to handle this stuff because it is ridiculously complex (as you know), but I'm not making much headway. Let me see if I can find the code path here where it is still running formula calculations. Does that function stop calculation in charts?

Comment: Are you using column autosizing? That should be only trigger for formula calculation that can override preCalculateFormulas false

Comment: No, but I am using auto filtering. I posted an edit to my question with a screenshot of further down in the stack trace. It appears that chart generation is what fires off the series of events resulting in formulas being calculated.

Comment: AutoFiltering doesn't use calculations IIRC, though it's been a while since I looked at that part of the code; but charts did.... though I thought I'd put a disable in the charting for that.... I'll check the code and see if I missed anything there

Comment: It looks like `writeChart` fires off a `refresh()` method for the chart, then that fires the same method for the PlotArea, then the DataSeries, then the DataSeriesValues. In `PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues`, the `refresh()` method runs `$calcEngine->_calculateFormulaValue(...)` with the `$pCell` value starting at A1. That then gets the worksheet as `$pCellParent` and then ends up doing something with the stack and checking some formulas. It's hard for me to follow without spending more time trying to understand it all.

Comment: Ok, it looks like the chart stuff tries to validate any cells that are referenced by the chart. We have some really complex formulas. Is there something I can do in my fork to stop it from trying to validate formulas when generating charts?

Comment: I've figured out what I feel is a reasonable solution to preventing charts from validating formulas using the `preCalculateFormulas` flag. For my use case it appears to be working and I am currently running my project off of my fork. I've submitted a PR back to PHPExcel, thanks for your help! https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/721

Answer (score 0):

I have never used PHPExcel but I can rephrase that formula from SUMIF/S() to SUMPRODUCTS for you. You can use Alt + Enter to make those massive formula somewhat readable.

To get your head around the sumproduct, Excel treats TRUE/FALSE as a 1/0 when any math operation is applied, so you can {TRUE,TRUE,FALSE} x {FALSE,TRUE,TRUE} to get {0,1,0}. Then SUMPRODUCT takes the {0,1,0} and multiplies it by the row/column totals you're trying to filter and then sums the values.

```
=IFERROR(
IF($L$3="UNITS",
COUNTIF('K1_Current_Accounts'!$M$2:$M$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!H5)
+COUNTIF('K1_Current_Available'!$M$2:$M$10000,'Snapshot Summary'!H5),
IF($L$3="Cost Basis",
SUMPRODUCT(--('K1_Current_Accounts'!$M$2:$M$10000='Snapshot Summary'!H5),'K1_Current_Accounts'!$E$2:$E$10000)
+SUMPRODUCT(--('K1_Current_Available'!$M$2:$M$10000='Snapshot Summary'!H5),'K1_Current_Available'!$E$2:$E$10000),
IF($L$3="Notes",
SUMPRODUCT('K1_Current_Accounts'!$AA$2:$AA$10000,--('K1_Current_Accounts'!$M$2:$M$10000='Snapshot Summary'!H5),--('K1_Current_Accounts'!$R$2:$R$10000='Snapshot Summary'!$A$7))
+SUMPRODUCT('K1_Current_Accounts'!$AA$2:$AA$10000,--('K1_Current_Accounts'!$M$2:$M$10000='Snapshot Summary'!H5),--('K1_Current_Accounts'!$R$2:$R$10000='Snapshot Summary'!$A$8))
+SUMPRODUCT('K1_Current_Accounts'!$AA$2:$AA$10000,--('K1_Current_Accounts'!$M$2:$M$10000='Snapshot Summary'!H5),--('K1_Current_Accounts'!$R$2:$R$10000='Snapshot Summary'!$A$9)),
IF($L$3="Cash",
SUMPRODUCT('K1_Historical_Accounts'!$AC$2:$AC$10000,--('K1_Historical_Accounts'!$M$2:$M$10000='Snapshot Summary'!H5),--('K1_Historical_Accounts'!$R$2:$R$10000='Snapshot Summary'!$A$10))))))
,"")
```